Email attachments being added inline after smtp host change
I have a Codeigniter 3.1.4 site that worked fine until the hosting company changed their email host.
I send emails from my site with PDFs attached, but the smtp provider was changed and I have updated the following values:
defined('PROTOCOL')        OR define('PROTOCOL', 'mail');
defined('SMTP_HOST')       OR define('SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.titan.email');

My code:
public function emailPDF ($id) {
    $timesheet = $this->timesheets_model->get_timesheets($id)[0];
    $filename = $this->getFilename($id);
    $master_company = 'company';
    $companyname = 'companyname';

    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['protocol'] = 'mail';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp0101.titan.email';
    $config['smtp_user'] = SMTP_USER;
    $config['smtp_pass'] = SMTP_PASS;
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;

    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
    $config['mailpath'] = MAILPATH;
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from($master_company->email);
    $this->email->to("{$company->email}");
    $filename = PDF_PATH . $filename;

    chmod($filename, 777);
    
    $this->email->attach($filename, 'attachment');

    $this->email->subject("Service Sheet for $companyname");

    $this->email->message("Hi,<br><br> Please find attached a Service Sheet");

    if($this->email->send()) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('level', 'success');

        // if ($this->timesheets_model->set_email_sent($id)) {
        //     $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Email sent successfully');
        // }
    } else {
        //show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'There was a problem sending the email');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('level', 'danger');
    }

}

emails still get sent but PDFs are not longer attached, they are added inline.
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_662fa8a442c93"--B_ALT_662fa8a442c93

   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitHi, Please find attached a Service Sheet for your company. Please do not reply to this email address as this account is not monitored.Regards

   --B_ALT_662fa8a442c93

   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

   Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printableHi,=3Cbr=3E=3Cbr=3E Please find attached a Service Sheet for your company=3Cbr=3E=3Cbr=3EPlease do not reply to this email addr=
ess as this account is not monitored.=3Cbr=3E=3Cbr=3ERegards,=3Cbr=3E.--B_ALT_662fa8a442c93--

   Content-Type: application/pdf; name="your+company-2024-04-29-090529-Alarm.pdf"

   Content-Disposition: inline;

   Content-Transfer-Encoding:    base64JVBERi0xLjMKMSAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovT3V0bGluZXMgMiAwIFIKL1BhZ2Vz
...

I have tried changing  $this->email->attach($filepath, 'inline'); to  $this->email->attach($filepath, 'attach');
The same happens with png's
no luck

post full code for more understanding

Looks an issue for the support of your hosting if your code worked perfectly with another SMTP host

Please keep in mind that CodeIgniter 3.1.4 is more than seven years old and has at least one public security issue. I don't want to ask which PHP version you use under the hood....

It seemed fairly obvious that the PDF attachment content was being merged into the email text itself, but the only config item that I could see that may affect that was this:
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";

But it's commonly reported that not enclosing this value in double quotes can cause problems, however not in my case, double quotes was the issue, enclosing them in single quotes fixed it!
